# PHP - Display small floating number as it is

Tags: php

I have to display a computed number and sometimes it is very small and it is displayed like this:

```
1.0E-8.
```

How can I display it like

```
0.00000001
```

Comment: How are you displaying said number. Show code please.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/number_format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
echo number_format($floatVariable, 8);
```

You could also read how many decimals are in the number beforehand... examples are on that link